# grunt-msdeploy for deploying AngularJS app to multiple servers

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, msdeploy

I am using grunt-msdeploy for deploying angularJs code to one of the server, this is working perfectly fine. I would like to deploy the same code to multiple servers. How do i achieve it ? Please help !

Gruntfile.js code for msdeploy:

```
    var path = require('path');
    //add the config file name
    var configFile = path.resolve('./deployconfig.json');
    var config = require(configFile);
msdeploy: {
            push: {
                options: {
                    verb: 'sync',
                    allowUntrusted: 'true',
                    source: {
                        'contentPath': path.resolve('./dist')
                    },
                    dest: {
                        contentPath: config.contentPath,
                        wmsvc: config.serverAddress,
                        userName: config.userName,
                        password: config.password
                    }
                }
            }
        }


grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-msdeploy');
 //add task for deployment - copying the dist from local server to remote server
 grunt.registerTask('deploy', ['msdeploy:push']);
```

deployconfig.json:

```
{
    "contentPath": "c:/inetpub/wwwroot/dist",
    "serverAddress": "ec2-xx-xx-xx-x.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
    "userName": "xxxxxxxxx",
    "password": "xxxxxxxxx"
}
```

I have tried using multiple dest in the msdeploy with multiple servers information in the json file, but that didn't work. Is there a way to do this at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working solution:

```
 msdeploy: {
            target1: {
                options: {
                    verb: 'sync',
                    allowUntrusted: 'true',
                    source: {
                        'contentPath': path.resolve('./dist')
                    },
                    dest: {
                        contentPath: "target1path",
                        wmsvc: "target1serverAddress",
                        userName:"target1userName",
                        password:"target1password"
                    }
                }
            },
            target2: {
                options: {
                    verb: 'sync',
                    allowUntrusted: 'true',
                    source: {
                        'contentPath': path.resolve('./dist')
                    },
                    dest: {
                        contentPath: "target2path",
                        wmsvc: "target2serverAddress",
                        userName:"target2userName",
                        password:"target2password"
                    }
                }
            }
        }

grunt.registerTask('deploy', ['msdeploy:target1', 'msdeploy:target2']);
```

In case if any one wants to do it with the config file , add multiple entries to the json config file like this:

```
[ 
  {
    "contentPath": "c:/inetpub/wwwroot/dist",
    "serverAddress": "ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
    "userName": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "password": "xxxxxxxxx"
  },
  {
    "contentPath": "c:/inetpub/wwwroot/dist",
    "serverAddress": "ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.ap-northeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
    "userName": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "password": "xxxxxxxxx"
  }
]
```

and the values can be referred as :

```
var path = require('path');
var configFile = path.resolve('./deployconfig.json');
var config = require(configFile);

contentPath: config[0].contentPath,
wmsvc: config[0].serverAddress,
userName: config[0].userName,
password: config[0].password
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you are configuring the task wrong, that's why it doesn't work in your case, it should be defined as taks for grunt, here's the pseudo-code:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  msdeploy: {
    options: {
      // Task-specific options go here.
    },
    your_target: {
      // Target-specific file lists and/or options go here.
    },
  },
});
```

More information and options [in the official manual](https://github.com/mrjackdavis/grunt-msdeploy).

**For multiple destinations** just create several `target` descriptions,

```
grunt.initConfig({
  msdeploy: {
    options: {
      // Task-specific options go here.
    },
    your_target_1: {
      // Target-specific file lists and/or options go here.
    },
    your_target_2: {
      // Target-specific file lists and/or options go here.
    },
    ...
  },
});
```

You may create `options`, generic for all of those `targets`, as well as specific `options` per each `target`.

When you'll run the task, simply do not specify which target you need to run, and it will execute them one by one:

```
// will be executed for all the targets from task `msdeploy` definition
grunt.registerTask('deploy', ['msdeploy']);

// or alternatively you may explicitly define the order of tasks:
grunt.registerTask('deploy', ['msdeploy:your_target_1', 'msdeploy:your_target_2']);
```

Comment: Ok,Thank you ! How do i register tasks for multiple destinations then if suppose i have mydest1 and mydest2? grunt.registerTask('deploy', ['msdeploy:push:mydest1']); ?

Comment: @Srini, find my answer in the edited answer, I extended for you this information.

Comment: thank you ! I tried the exact way above as mentioned but its not accepting any other name apart from dest for my different targets. When i provide multile dest's its deploying to only first sever.

Comment: you are welcome, @Srini, glad if my input helped you with your business. Feel free to choose the answer, if there will be no better options. Thanks.

Comment: Tried msdeploy: {
            options: {
                verb: 'sync',
                allowUntrusted: 'true',
                source: {
                    'contentPath': path.resolve('./dist')
                }
            },
            target1: {
             //server 1 details here
            },
            target2: {
                //server 2 details here
            }         
        } . Its throwing Error: A '-dest' argument must be specified with the 'sync' verb. Any idea ?

Comment: @Srini, but you did it wrong, please, check the manual. These options, have to be defined on level of the `target` definition. You forgotten to specify the `dest` argument, and specified only `src`... It clearly says: "`dest` Specifies the destination of a synchronization operation. The destination argument is required only if the `sync` or `delete` verb is specified. "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105585/discussion-between-farside-and-srini).